# program causes memory corruption

Tags: c

Below is my attempt to write a program which calculates the determinant and the inverse of a nxn matrix. The program returns a valid inverse matrix when 1<=n<=3. However, when n>=4, the program returns `a.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast) followed by showing the backtrace and the memory map when it trys to calculate the inverse matrix. Could someone tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  int m, n; double ** entry;
} MATRIX;

double ** make_2d_array ( int m, int n )
{
  double ** array = (double**) calloc(m, sizeof(double*));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<m; ++i)
  { array[i] = (double*) calloc(n, sizeof(double)); }

  return array;
}

MATRIX * make_matrix ( int m, int n )
{
  MATRIX * matrix = (MATRIX *) calloc(1, sizeof(MATRIX));
  matrix->m = m; matrix->n = n;
  matrix->entry = make_2d_array ( m, n );
  return matrix;
}

MATRIX * read_matrix ()
{
  int m, n;
  MATRIX * matrix;
  scanf("%d %d", &m, &n );
  matrix = make_matrix ( m, n );

  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      double x;
      scanf("%lf", &x);
      matrix->entry[i][j] = x;
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

MATRIX * del_row_col ( int r, int c, MATRIX * matrix )  //function which removes the rth row and the cth column
{
  int i,j;
  MATRIX * output = make_matrix ( matrix->m-1, matrix->n-1 );

  for ( i=r; i<matrix->m-1; ++i )
  {
    for ( j=c; j<matrix->n-1; ++j )
    {
      output->entry[i][j] = matrix->entry[i+1][j+1]; }
  }
  for ( i=0; i<r; ++i )
  {
    for ( j=0; j<c; ++j )
    {
      output->entry[i][j] = matrix->entry[i][j]; }
  }
  for ( i=r; i<matrix->m-1; ++i )
  {
    for ( j=0; j<c; ++j )
    {
      output->entry[i][j] = matrix->entry[i+1][j]; }
  }
  for ( i=0; i<r; ++i )
  {
    for ( j=c; j<matrix->n; ++j )
    {
      output->entry[i][j] = matrix->entry[i][j+1]; }
  }
  return output;
}

void free_2d_array ( int m, double ** array )
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<m; i++)
  {
    free(array[i]);
  }
  free(array);
}

void free_matrix ( MATRIX * matrix )
{
  free_2d_array ( matrix->m, matrix->entry );
  free(matrix);
}

double det( MATRIX * matrix )
{
  int i;
  if ( matrix->n == 1 )
  {
    return matrix->entry[0][0];
  }
  else
  {
    int s=1;
    double d=0;
    for (i=0; i<matrix->n; i++)
    {
      MATRIX * submatrix = del_row_col ( 0, i, matrix );
      d += s*(matrix->entry[0][i])*det(submatrix);
      s *= -1;
      free_matrix(submatrix);      //prevents memory leak
    }
    return d;
  }
}

int power ( int n )  //calculates (-1)^n 
{
  if ( n%2==0 )
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else if( n%2==1 )
  {
    return -1;
  }
}

MATRIX * inverse ( MATRIX * matrix )
{
  MATRIX * inv = make_matrix ( matrix->m, matrix->n );
  int i,j;
  if (matrix->m==1)
  {
    inv->entry[0][0] = 1/det(matrix);
    return inv;
  }
  else
  {
    for (i=0; i<matrix->m; ++i)
    {
      for (j=0; j<matrix->n; ++j)
      {
        double d = 1/det(matrix);
        inv->entry[i][j] = d*power(i+j)*det( del_row_col ( j, i, matrix ));
      }
    }
    return inv;
  }
}

void print_matrix ( MATRIX * matrix )
{
  int i, j;
  printf("%d %d\n", matrix->m, matrix->n);
  for (i=0; i<matrix->m; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<matrix->n; j++)
    {
      printf(" %6g", matrix->entry[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main()
{
  MATRIX * matrix = read_matrix();
  print_matrix(matrix);
  if (matrix->m != matrix->n )
  {
    printf("matrix has no determinant\n");
  }
  else
  {
    double x = det(matrix);
    printf("determinant %f\n", x);
  }
  printf("inverse \n");
  if (det(matrix) != 0)
  {
    MATRIX * i = inverse(matrix);
    print_matrix(i);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("matrix is not invertible\n");
  }
}
```

The program only returns the correct inverse when 1<=n<=3 e.g.

```
cat 3x3
2 0 0 
0 2 0
0 0 2

a.out < 3x3
3 3
      2      0      0
      0      2      0
      0      0      2
determinant 8.000000
inverse
3 3
    0.5     -0      0
     -0    0.5     -0
      0     -0    0.5
```

when n=4:

```
a.out < id
4 4
      1     -2      2      2
      1     -3      3      4
     -2      5     -4     -6
     -1      3     -6     -2
determinant -2.000000
inverse
*** Error in `a.out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast):...
```

Comment: The code you posted has two definitions of `free_2d_array` and none of `free_matrix`. Those issues prevent it from compiling. With those fixed, it does not crash for me when given a 4×4 matrix. You have only shown sample input for cases you say work. Show sample input for a case that does not work.

Comment: `det( del_row_col ( j, i, matrix ))` leaks memory (memory allocated by `del_row_col` is lost).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Sorry for that. It was a copy and paste error. I've updated my post.

Comment: When I run the updated code with the input shown for a 4×4 matrix, I do not get a crash, and I get correct results. I do not see any error in the code. Check whether you are compiling and running the same code that is currently posted in the question. If that fails, trace your program in a debugger and/or insert `printf` statements to follow its progress throughout its execution.